# Restler 3.0 Basic Authentication

Tags: php, basic-authentication, restler

I'm trying out Restler to build web api for my new project.
One of requirements is simple authentication.
I found nice example on SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/7969250/965722 but it's for Restler 2.
Using manual I managed to convert that class to Restler 3.0

```
<?php
class BasicAuthentication implements iAuthenticate
{
    const REALM = 'Restricted API';
    public static $currentUser;
    public static $requires = 'user';
    public static $role = 'user';

    public function __isAllowed()
    {
        if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']))
        {
            $user = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
            $pass = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];
            $user = mysql_real_escape_string($user);
            $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($pass);

            $roles = array('12345' => 'user', '67890' => 'admin');

            if (!isset($pass) || !array_key_exists($pass, $roles))
            {
                return false;
            }

            static ::$role = $roles[$pass];
            Resources::$accessControlFunction = 'AccessControl::verifyAccess';
            return static ::$requires == static ::$role || static ::$role == 'admin';
        }
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="' . self::REALM . '"');
        throw new RestException(401, 'Basic Authentication Required');
    }

    /**
     * @access private
     */
    public static function verifyAccess(array $m)
    {
        $requires = isset($m['class']['AccessControl']['properties']['requires']) ? $m['class']['AccessControl']['properties']['requires'] : false;
        return $requires ? static ::$role == 'admin' || static ::$role == $requires : true;
    }
}
?>
```

My sample api class looks like so:

```
<?php
class Api
{
    /**
     * @url GET
     * @url GET hello
     * @url GET hello/{to}
     */
    function hello($to = 'world')
    {
        return "Hello $to!";
    }
    /**
     * @access protected
     * @class  AccessControl {@requires user}
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return "protected api, only user and admin can access";
    }
    /**
     * @access protected
     * @class  AccessControl {@requires admin}
     */
    public function admin()
    {
        return "protected api, only admin can access";
    }
}
```

any my index.php

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/restler.php';
use Luracast\Restler\Restler;

$r = new Restler();
$r->addAPIClass('Api', '');
$r->addAuthenticationClass('BasicAuthentication');
$r->handle();
?>
```

When I navigate to my webpage standard login and password form shows, but even if I put correct username and password nothing happens - login window reopens.

I'm probably making some silly mistake, but I can't find it.
This is my first attempt to basic authentication, so please be kind.

Do I need some special configuration on server?

**EDIT:**
It looks like I need some special config because my server runs as CGI/FastCGI.
I've tried adding code from this comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php#106285
but I am unable to configure .htaccess correctly.
This is the default Restler htaccess file:

```
Options -MultiViews
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag display_errors Off
</IfModule>
```

and these lines are required by workaround from previous link to work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},last]
```

How to combine both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why but I had to implement `iUseAuthentication` in my `BasicAuthentication` class. (there's nothing in docs about it, probably because this is RC release and docs and samples are modified).
This way everything started working.
Also I modified htaccess like so:

```
Options -MultiViews
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},last]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag display_errors Off
</IfModule>
```

Hope this helps someone :)

**EDIT:**
I've found my code and I'm posting it here, maybe someone will find it usefull.

```
<?php
use \Luracast\Restler\iAuthenticate;
use \Luracast\Restler\Resources;
class BasicAuthentication implements iAuthenticate
{
    const REALM = 'Restricted API';
    public static $requires = 'user';
    public static $role = 'user';

    public function __isAllowed()
    {
        //set http auth headers for apache+php-cgi work around
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']) && preg_match('/Basic\s+(.*)$/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], $matches))
        {
            list($name, $password) = explode(':', base64_decode($matches[1]));
            $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] = strip_tags($name);
            $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] = strip_tags($password);
        }

        //set http auth headers for apache+php-cgi work around if variable gets renamed by apache
        if (isset($_SERVER['REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']) && preg_match('/Basic\s+(.*)$/i', $_SERVER['REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], $matches))
        {
            list($name, $password) = explode(':', base64_decode($matches[1]));
            $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] = strip_tags($name);
            $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] = strip_tags($password);
        }
        if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']))
        {
            $user = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
            $pass = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];

            $roles = array('12345' => 'user', '67890' => 'admin');

            if (!isset($pass) || !array_key_exists($pass, $roles))
            {
                return false;
            }

            static ::$role = $roles[$pass];
            Resources::$accessControlFunction = 'BasicAuthentication::verifyAccess';
            $x = static ::$requires == static ::$role || static ::$role == 'admin';

                        $file = 'a.txt';
            $current = file_get_contents($file);
            $current .= static ::$requires." ".static::$role . "\n";
            file_put_contents($file, $current);

            return $x;
        }
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="' . self::REALM . '"');
        throw new RestException(401, 'Basic Authentication Required');
    }

    /**
     * @access private
     */
    public static function verifyAccess(array $m)
    {
        $requires = isset($m['class']['BasicAuthentication']['properties']['requires']) ? $m['class']['BasicAuthentication']['properties']['requires'] : false;

                                $file = 'a.txt';
            $current = file_get_contents($file);
            $current .= $requires." - ".static::$role . "\n";
            file_put_contents($file, $current);
        return $requires ? static ::$role == 'admin' || static ::$role == $requires : true;
    }
}
?>
```

and my sample API class:

```
<?php
class Api implements iUseAuthentication
{
    private $_authenticated = false;
    /**
     * This method will be called first for filter classes and api classes so
     * that they can respond accordingly for filer method call and api method
     * calls
     *
     *
     * @param bool $isAuthenticated passes true when the authentication is
     *                              done, false otherwise
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __setAuthenticationStatus($isAuthenticated = false)
    {
        $this->_authenticated = $isAuthenticated;
    }

    /**
     * @access protected
     * @class  BasicAuthentication {@requires user}
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return "protected api, only user and admin can access";
    }
    /**
     * @access protected
     * @class  BasicAuthentication {@requires admin}
     */
    public function admin()
    {
        return "protected api, only admin can access";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: @Misiiu do you mean in this line: class BasicAuthentication implements iAuthenticate   instead of iAuthenticate you had to use iUseAuthentication

Comment: @ZeeshanJan I've edited my answer. I've posted my BasicAuthentication class and sample API class that implements `iUseAuthentication`. All You must do is when You create Restler instance You must add `$r->addAuthenticationClass('BasicAuthentication');`. Hope this helps! :)